# Best approach to populate new tables in a database

Tags: sql

I have a problem I have been working on the past several hours. It is complex (for me) and I don't expect someone to do it for me. I just need the right direction.

Problem: We had the tables (below) added to our database and I need to update them based off of data already in our DailyCosts table. The tricky part is that I need to take DailyCosts.Notes and move it to PurchaseOrder.PoNumber. Notes is where we currenlty have the PONumbers.

I started with the Insert below, testing it out on one WellID. This is Inserting records from our DailyCosts table to the new PurchaseOrder table:

```
Insert Into PurchaseOrder (PoNumber,WellId,JObID,ID)
Select Distinct Cast(Notes As nvarchar(20)), WellID, JOBID, 
DailyCosts.DailyCostID
From DailyCosts
Where WellID =  '24A-23'
```

It affected 1973 rows (The Notes are in Ntext)

However, I need to update the other new tables because we need to see the actual PONumbers in the application.

This next Insert is Inserting records from our DailyCost table and new PurchaseOrder table (from above) to a new table called PurchaseOrderDailyCost

```
Insert Into PurchaseOrderDailyCost (WellID, JobID, ReportNo, AccountCode, PurchaseOrderID,ID,DailyCostSeqNo, DailyCostID)
Select Distinct DailyCosts.WellID,DailyCosts.JobID,DailyCosts.ReportNo,DailyCosts.AccountCode,
PurchaseOrder.ID,NEWID(),0,DailyCosts.DailyCostID
From DailyCosts join
PurchaseOrder ON DailyCosts.WellID = PurchaseOrder.WellID
Where DailyCosts.WellID = '24A-23'
```

Unfortunately, this produces 3,892,729 records. The Notes field contains the same list of PONumbers each day. This is by design so that the people inputting the data out in the field can easily track their PO numbers. The new PONumber column that we are moving the Notes to would store just unique POnumbers. I modified the query by replacing NEWID() with DailyCostID and the Join `to ON DailyCosts.DailyCostID = PurchaseOrder.ID` 
This affected 1973 rows the same as the first Insert.

The next Insert looks like this:

```
Insert Into PurchaseOrderAccount (WellID, JobID, PurchaseOrderID, ID, AccountCode)
Select PurchaseOrder.WellID, PurchaseOrder.JobID, PurchaseOrder.ID, PurchaseOrderDailyCost.DailyCostID,PurchaseOrderDailyCost.AccountCode 
From PurchaseOrder Inner Join
PurchaseOrderDailyCost ON PurchaseOrder.ID = PurchaseOrderDailyCost.DailyCostID
Where PurchaseOrder.WellID = '24A-23'
```

The page in the application now shows the PONumbers in the correct column. Everything looks like I want it to.
Unfortunately, it slows down the application to an unacceptable level. I need to figure out how to either modify my Insert or delete duplicate records. The problem is that there are multiple foreign key constraints.  I have some more information below for reference.

[This shows the application after the inserts. These are all duplicate records that I am hoping to elminate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMaNT.png)

Here is some additional information I received from the vendor about the tables:

```
-- add a new purchase order
INSERT INTO PurchaseOrder
                         (WellID, JobID, ID, PONumber, Amount, Description)
VALUES        ('MyWell', 'MyJob', NEWID(), 'PO444444', 500.0, 'A new Purchase Order')

-- link a purchase order with id 'A356FBF4-A19B-4466-9E5C-20C5FD0E95C3' to a DailyCost record with SeqNo 0 and AccountCode 'MyAccount'
INSERT INTO PurchaseOrderDailyCost
                         (WellID, JobID, ReportNo, AccountCode, DailyCostSeqNo, PurchaseOrderID, ID)
VALUES        ('MyWell', 'MyJob', 4, 'MyAccount', 0, 'A356FBF4-A19B-4466-9E5C-20C5FD0E95C3', NEWID())

-- link a purchase order with id 'A356FBF4-A19B-4466-9E5C-20C5FD0E95C3' to an account code 'MyAccount'
-- (i.e. make it choosable from the DailyCost PO-column dropdown for any DailyCost record whose account code is 'MyAccount')
INSERT INTO PurchaseOrderAccount
                         (WellID, JobID, PurchaseOrderID, ID, AccountCode)
VALUES        ('MyWell', 'MyJob', 'A356FBF4-A19B-4466-9E5C-20C5FD0E95C3', NEWID(), 'MyAccount')

-- link a purchase order with id 'A356FBF4-A19B-4466-9E5C-20C5FD0E95C3' to an AFE No. 'MyAFENo'
-- (same behavior as with the account codes above)
INSERT INTO PurchaseOrderAFE
                         (WellID, JobID, PurchaseOrderID, ID, AFENo)
VALUES        ('MyWell', 'MyJob', 'A356FBF4-A19B-4466-9E5C-20C5FD0E95C3', NEWID(), 'MyAFENo')
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I found this bit confusing... "*unfortunately, it slows down the application to an unacceptable level.*" Are you implying you're doing these migrations on a live production system? Is this a one time migration? Or something you plan on doing on an ongoing basis?

Comment: Have you run an `explain` on the `select` portion of your `insert...selects`? Are `PurchaseOrderDailyCost.DailyCostID` and `PurchaseOrder.WellID` indexed?

Comment: It's my test database but is structured exactly the same as production. The Database connects to the application. Basically, after I load the data from these inserts and click on the costs tab in the application it takes about 20 seconds to load.

Comment: Honestly I am farily new still to SQL, especially inserts and deletes. I will run an explain and see what I get.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out I missed some simple joining principles. The better I get the more silly mistakes I seem to make. Basically, on my very first insert, I did not include a Group By. Adding this took my INSERT from 1973 to 93. Then on my next insert, I joined DailyCosts.Notes on PurchaseOrder.PONumber since these are the only records from DailyCosts I needed. This was previously INSERT 2 on my question. From there basically, everything came together. Two steps forward an one step back. Thanks to everyone that responded to this.